# Best way to create a service that inserts a complex entity

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Hope you are all healthy!

I have a situation in which I have a backend application that exposes a rest api to create data related to expense reporting. The main entity that this API allows to be created is an "Expense Report" which has other entities related to it, such as the country on which the expenses took place and the user that created it.

Thing is, my controller receives a DTO, converts it into a JPA entity and then sends it to the service class. In my service class, I have to check if a related entity field like the username for User or the country code for Country, and then go into the corresponding entity repository and get the corresponding entity.

```
public ExpenseReport save(ExpenseReport expenseReport) {
        if (expenseReport.getId() != null) {
            expenseReportRepository.findById(expenseReport.getId())
                    .ifPresent(currentObject -> {
                        expenseReport.setId(currentObject.getId());
                        expenseReport.setVersion(currentObject.getVersion());
                    });
        }

        if (expenseReport.getUser() != null && expenseReport.getUser().getUsername() != null) {
            String username = expenseReport.getUser().getUsername();
            userRepository.findByUsername(username)
                    .ifPresentOrElse(user -> {
                                expenseReport.setUser(user);
                            },
                            () -> {
                                throw new InvalidDataException(User.class, "username", username);
                            });

        }

        if (expenseReport.getCountry() != null && expenseReport.getCountry().getCode() != null) {
            String countryCode = expenseReport.getCountry().getCode();
            countryRepository.findByCode(countryCode)
                    .ifPresentOrElse(country -> {
                                expenseReport.setCountry(country);
                            },
                            () -> {
                                throw new InvalidDataException(Country.class, "countryCode", countryCode);
                            });

        }

        for (ExpenseItem expenseItem : expenseReport.getExpenses()) {
            if (expenseItem.getCurrency() != null && expenseItem.getCurrency().getCode() != null) {
                String currencyCode = expenseItem.getCurrency().getCode();
                currencyRepository.findByCode(currencyCode)
                        .ifPresentOrElse(currency -> {
                                    expenseItem.setCurrency(currency);
                                },
                                () -> {
                                    throw new InvalidDataException(Currency.class, "currencyCode", currencyCode);
                                });
            }

            if (expenseItem.getExpenseCity() != null && expenseItem.getExpenseCity().getCode() != null) {
                String expenseCityCode = expenseItem.getExpenseCity().getCode();
                cityRepository.findByCode(expenseCityCode)
                        .ifPresentOrElse(city -> {
                                    expenseItem.setExpenseCity(city);
                                },
                                () -> {
                                    throw new InvalidDataException(City.class, "expenseCityCode", expenseCityCode);
                                });
            }

            if (expenseItem.getCategory() != null && expenseItem.getCategory().getCode() != null) {
                String categoryCode = expenseItem.getCategory().getCode();
                categoryRepository.findByCode(categoryCode)
                        .ifPresentOrElse(expenseCategory -> {
                                    expenseItem.setCategory(expenseCategory);
                                },
                                () -> {
                                    throw new InvalidDataException(ExpenseCategory.class, "expenseCategoryCode", categoryCode);
                                });
            }
        }

        return expenseReportRepository.save(expenseReport);
    }
```

My question is, is this the best way to do this? I feel that if the object gets too complex, I'll have to create this super huge save method.

Does JPA offer a better solution to this? I was thinking also to change the parameterized types (like country, city, state) to use the code itself as it's primary key, rather than an auto-generated id.

Regards.

Comment: Validation of your data should be separate from the saving of the data.

Comment: You can get a lot of validation for free during deserialisation by using javax.validation annotations.